# how create a pinned notification

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want make notification like ADM notification to be always pinned on the notifications on phone and user only can ignore notification just with the button on the notification
How I can do that

[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIzXA.jpg)

I create the notification but I want pinned that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it through `flutter_local_notification` plugin.

In that plugin, `onGoing` Notification facility is present so we can use it and enjoy ongoing notification

Answer (score 0):

only work i must do that just set the ongoing condition in NotificationDetails to true :)

```html
 notificationDetails() {
return const NotificationDetails(
    android: AndroidNotificationDetails('channelId', 'channelName',
        autoCancel: false,
        importance: Importance.max,
    ongoing: true,
      enableVibration: false),
    iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails());
  }
```

and next create a dart file form example notification services and

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).